# Getting a List of My Email Recipients who have viewed my email?

Tags: email, html-email, hit

Trying to get a list of my email recipients who have seen my email, and then to use a different medium to address who didn't see (via SMS/Call).

I could get the number of people who saw the email by having a hit counter set up in a web server, looking for a method to get this done now. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done reliably. Popular email clients will not do anything to alert the sender that an email was received because this allows spammers to detect if the email address is valid. That's why most email clients block remote images until the user clicks "Show Images" because the images could be used for this purpose.

Email system support something called a "read receipt" that is intended for this use but most clients will never send one.

You can detect if an email bounces but receiving an email and viewing an email are two different things.